# Scrapy dont save values to items

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Since today, my spider wont save any information to my items "DuifpicturesItem".
I got almost the same spider created for a different customer, but this one wont save anything, idk why. My items.py only have two fields: Images and Link

In my console, i can see, that i collects the right data, but it doenst save it

**My Code**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import DuifpicturesItem
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
import csv

class DuifLogin(CrawlSpider):
    name = "duiflogin"
    allowed_domains = ['duif.nl']
    login_page = 'https://www.duif.nl/login'
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS' : ['SKU', 'Title', 'Price', 'Link', 'Title_small', 'NL_PL_PC', 'Description' ] }
    with open("duifonlylinks.csv","r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        start_urls = [items['Link'] for items in reader]
        
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(),
            callback='parse_page',
            follow=True
            ),
    )         
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url=self.login_page,
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter=True
        )    

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'username' : '****',
            'password' : '****',
            'submit' : ''
        },  callback=self.after_loging)

    def after_loging(self, response):
        accview = response.xpath('//div[@class="c-accountbox clearfix js-match-height"]/h3')
        if accview:
            print('success')
        else:
            print(':(') 

        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        productpage = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-details col-md-12"]')
        
        if not productpage:
            print('No product', response.url)

        for a in productpage:
            
            items = DuifpicturesItem()
            items['Link'] = response.url
            items['Images'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="inner"]/img/@src').getall()
            yield items
```

**My console**
[image]
here you can see, that it scrapes links and images like i want to, but the .csv/.json file still empty

**P.S**
the login data isnt correct, but for this proccess, i dont have to be login, so i guess, it doenst effect the crawling process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what you mean by "save it". Since you made no mention to a pipeline, I'm assuming you don't have one for handling your items, so your Items are beign kept on memory only.

If you want to save your scraped items into a file you need to use the [feed export](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html). Simplest way would be:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o items.json
```

*It supports other formats, check the documentation.*

If you meant to save into a DB or do something else with the data check the [ItemPipelines](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

Comment: hey sir, i used the same command like you wrote, but i chose csv format. My file is always empty, it still got 0 bytes, no matter how long i let my spider crawl. My goal is to have a .csv/.json file, which got the piclinks and the productlinks stored in it.

Comment: Hi y.y, can you provide the execution logs then? If the items are not exported it usually means they weren't scraped.

Comment: i edited my question and uploaded a screenshot of my console, thanks in advance!

Comment: @y.y in the future, please don't post logs as screenshots, copy and paste them in your question. On another note, I haven't noticed that you were using `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` in your custom settings. This setting will filter the exports to only the fields included in the list. `Link` is there, `Images` is not. I've also executed your spider, as it is, and it managed to scrape the `Link` field. Adjust your `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` and rescrape, that should resolve the issue.

Comment: ok i will. Are the logs the things that are loaded at the beginning or is the important stuff at the end? Unfortunately i posted the wrong code :S i got my program working now!

Comment: Depends on the situation, most commonly the middle. Glad to hear you got it working. If the problem is solved, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.